# CakePHP's list problem

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this table in my DB:

```
Group

 - ID-Name
 - 1 -abc
 - 2 -def
 - 3 -ghi

Pages

 - id-group_id-name
 - 1 -1       -home
 - 2 -1       -about us
```

Now I wanted to make a select box that groups them by 'group' using:

```
function add() {

$this->set('pages', $this->Page->find('list', array('fields' => array('Page.id', 'Page.name', 'Page.group_id'))));

}
```

**In my add.ctp:**

```
echo $form->input('group_id', array('options' => $pages));
```

The output:

```
<select name="data[Page][id]" id="PageId">
<optgroup label="1">
<option value="1">Home</option>
<option value="2">About Us</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

I wanted the optgroup to display the actual group name not the group id like:

```
<select name="data[Page][id]" id="PageId">
<optgroup label="abc">
<option value="1">Home</option>
<option value="2">About Us</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

I have tried this one:

```
$this->Page->find('list', array('conditions' => 'Group.id = Page.id', 'fields' => array('Page.id', 'Page.name', 'Group.name')));
```

But 'Group.id' and 'Group.name' is unknown.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show all of the code involved in creating that select box? 

You generally define optgroups by passing an array name like this:
   1.  <?php echo $form->input('field', array('options' => array(
   2. 'Label1' => array(
   3. 'Value 1'=>'Label 1',
   4. 'Value 2'=>'Label 2'
   5. ),
   6. 'Label2' => array(
   7. 'Value 3'=>'Label 3'
   8. )
   9. ))); ?>

Comment: I really have been figuring this out, my same question can be found here http://cakeqs.org/eng/questions/view/find_list_problem.
I hope this can help you guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->Page->find('list', array(
    "fields" => array("Page.id", "Page.name", "Group.name"),
    "joins" => array(
        array(
            "table" => "groups",
            "alias" => "Group",
            "type" => "INNER",
            "conditions" => array("Group.id = Page.id")
        )
    ),
    "order" => array(...) // whatever ordering you want
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while ...

```
$this->Page->find('list', array('conditions' => 'Group.id = Page.id', 'fields' => array('Page.id', 'Page.name', 'Group.name'),'recursive'=0));
```

Otherwise find("list") uses recursive = -1 and won't load the group data

Answer (score 1):

Implementing Select box in option group in cakephp is a very simple task.

Follow the given steps to implement option group.

for example if you have two tables:

1. Category,
2. Subcategory

Create model for both table and add one line in subcategory model,

```
var $belongsTo = array('Category');
```

So your subcategory model look like

```
class Subcategory extends AppModel 
{
    var $name = 'Subcategory';
    var $belongsTo = array('Category');
}

Now come to controller part

$this->set('subcategory',$this->Subcategory->find('list', array(
    "fields" => array("Subcategory.id", "Subcategory.field2", "Category.field1"),
    "joins" => array(
            array(
                    "table" => "categories",
                    "alias" => "Category",
                    "type" => "INNER",
                    "conditions" => array("Category.id = Subcategory.category_id")
            )
    ),
)));?>
```

Task in view part

```
<?php 
echo $form->input('subcategory_id',array('type'=>'select','options'=>$subcategory));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether your Page and Group models are properly associated:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/78/Associations-Linking-Models-Together

But at the very least, you probably need to load the Group model in the Page controller where you have the $this->Page->find(..) lookup like so:

```
$this->loadModel('Group');

$this->Page->find('list', array('conditions' => 'Group.id = Page.id', 'fields' => array('Page.id', 'Page.name', 'Group.name')));
```

Answer (score 0):

also, 'group' => 'Group.name' is another param you can set for find. It will setup a GROUP BY in the SQL.